# Started Grafana, but no logs or server at localhost:3000?

Tags: homebrew, grafana

I'm trying to follow the instructions at https://grafana.com/docs/installation/mac/ to install Grafana locally on a Mac. I've installed Grafana using `brew install grafana`, then started it using `brew services start grafana`:

```
> brew services list | grep grafana
grafana    started kurt /Users/kurt/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.grafana.plist
```

However, I don't see any Grafana admin page at `localhost:3000`:

```
> curl http://localhost:3000/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
```

Also, I don't see any log file at `/usr/local/var/log/grafana/grafana.log` as documented there:

```
> tail -f /usr/local/var/log/grafana/grafana.log
tail: /usr/local/var/log/grafana/grafana.log: No such file or directory
```

How can I interact with Grafana now that it's (supposedly) running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing it using the instructions for Docker (https://grafana.com/docs/installation/docker/):

```
> docker run \
                                                -d \
                                                -p 3000:3000 \
                                                --name=grafana \
                                                -e "GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=http://grafana.server.name" \
                                                -e "GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret" \
                                                grafana/grafana
```

and can now see a login page (where I logged in with the default username `admin` and specified password `secret`):

[image]

I still don't know why the MacOS installation didn't work though?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some issue with launchd plist? Executing "brew services start grafana -v" yields:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.grafana</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/grafana/bin/grafana-server</string>
        <string>--config</string>
        <string>/usr/local/etc/grafana/grafana.ini</string>
        <string>--homepath</string>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/grafana/share/grafana</string>
        <string>--packaging=brew</string>
        <string>cfg:default.paths.logs=/usr/local/var/log/grafana</string>
        <string>cfg:default.paths.data=/usr/local/var/lib/grafana</string>
        <string>cfg:default.paths.plugins=/usr/local/var/lib/grafana/plugins</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/log/grafana-stderr.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/log/grafana-stdout.log</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/lib/grafana</string>
   </dict>
   </plist>
/bin/launchctl enable gui/501/homebrew.mxcl.grafana
/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/cmore/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.grafana.plist
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/cmore/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.grafana.plist` exited with 5.
```

If one takes the strings from the array and executes them on the command line, then grafana starts up:

```
/usr/local/opt/grafana/bin/grafana-server --config /usr/local/etc/grafana/grafana.ini --homepath /usr/local/opt/grafana/share/grafana --packaging=brew cfg:default.paths.logs=/usr/local/var/log/grafana cfg:default.paths.data=/usr/local/var/lib/grafana cfg:default.paths.plugins=/usr/local/var/lib/grafana/plugins
```